# Is setting CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y safe?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, root

I was playing around with `/dev/mem` and found out that even as root user you cannot access the whole file if `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y`.

It was new to me that there are mechanisms to prevent the root user from doing what he likes.

But as root I could simply alter the Linux kernel image and reboot (to disable the restriction). If the kernel image file is somehow protected I could still write to `/dev/sda` or whatever the main disk is.

So my question is if settings `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y` is safe or is it easy for the root user to bypass?

Comment: You cannot protect yourself from the root user unless we are talking about RO storage. `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y` will do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Security is layers, one single thing can seldom do everything. The system could boot from read-only storage, or have secure mechanisms to only boot a signed kernel. (And if you're lucky, no run-time way to change the boot settings.) In any case, a malware that has to modify the kernel and reboot would be quite a bit more noticeable than one that just silently does its thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of [`STRICT_DEVMEM`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5.5/source/lib/Kconfig.debug#L1838) isn’t to fully protect the system from its owner, it’s to prevent accidental writes to `/dev/mem`:

> If this option is disabled, you allow userspace (root) access to all
> of memory, including kernel and userspace memory. Accidental
> access to this is obviously disastrous, but specific access can
> be used by people debugging the kernel.

It also makes a number of attack scenarios against the running system more difficult, but it doesn’t protect the system at rest.